# Android Realtime accelerometer graph AChartEngine

Tags: android

Hi I'M making realtime graph by plotting SensorManager xyz but I have error.

My graph is working in normal activity but I'm trying to place it on Fragment because I will use iton viewpager with tablayout here's my code.

**Note:**

1. `Sensor data have no problem`
2. `Graph is working in my first project I just transfer it on new project`

**LineGraph Java:**

```
 public class LineGraph {

private TimeSeries dataset = new TimeSeries("");

private TimeSeries dataset2 = new TimeSeries("");
private TimeSeries dataset3 = new TimeSeries("");

private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

private XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
private XYSeriesRenderer renderer2 = new XYSeriesRenderer();

private XYSeriesRenderer renderer3 = new XYSeriesRenderer();

private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

private GraphicalView view;

public LineGraph() {

    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    mRenderer.setYLabels(0);
    mDataset.addSeries(dataset);

    renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    renderer.setFillPoints(false);
    renderer.setLineWidth(10f);

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    mDataset.addSeries(dataset2);
    renderer2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    renderer2.setFillPoints(false);
    renderer2.setLineWidth(10f);


    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{0,0,0,0});

    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer2);


    mDataset.addSeries(dataset3);

    renderer3.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer3.setFillPoints(false);
    renderer3.setLineWidth(10f);


    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer3);

}

public GraphicalView getView(Context context) {

    view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, mDataset, mRenderer);
    return view;
}

public void addNewPoints(Point p) {
    dataset.add(p.getX(), p.getY());
    dataset2.add(p.getX2(), p.getY2());

    dataset3.add(p.getX3(), p.getY3());
}

}
```

**Shake Fragment Java << fragment to use in main java**

```
 public class Shake extends Fragment implements SensorEventListener {

private Sensor mySensor;
private SensorManager sensorManager;

public static GraphicalView view;
private LineGraph line = new LineGraph();
private LinearLayout ll;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shake, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().SENSOR_SERVICE);

    mySensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    sensorManager.registerListener(this, mySensor, sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    ll = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.accelerometer_chart);

    view = line.getView(getActivity()); // Error here

    ll.addView(view);

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sensor Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Point p = MockData.getDataFromReceiver(1, event.values[0], 2, event.values[1], 3, event.values[2]);

    line.addNewPoints(p);

    view.repaint();

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
}
```

I debug it and It's seem I have error in

**view = line.getView(getActivity());**

because with out this line, project is working but no view of graph.

**getView method from LineGraph java**

```
public GraphicalView getView(Context context) {

view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, mDataset, mRenderer);
return view;
 }
```

**LOGCAT ERROR**

```
06-23 03:51:37.835 26465-26465/seismic.squareup.com.ushake   E/AndroidRuntime:  FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException
at seismic.squareup.com.ushake.Shake.onCreate(Shake.java:49)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1951)                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1029)                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:926)                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:876)                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1175)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look on the [Android Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=en) on the official documentation, you'll see that `onCreate()` is being called before 'onCreateView()' and 'onActivityCreated()'. This means that in `onCreate()` your fragment's view is not created yet, and a fragment itself is not attached to `Actvity` so far. And you can't use `getActivity()`.

Move your initialization into `onActivityCreated()` method